# What is the difference between the holding torque and stall torque of a motor?

Tags: motor, servomotor, stepper-motor

Do the terms holding torque and stall torque imply the same thing? The information on torque for these [stepper motors](https://www.pololu.com/category/87/stepper-motors) is given as holding torque. While these [servo motors](https://www.servocity.com/2000-series-dual-mode-servo-25-2) have the torque given as stall torque. My hope is to use the maximum torque a motor can handle to compare different motors for a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both holding torque for a stepper motor, and stall torque for a servo motor, refer to the maximum amount of torque when the shaft is not spinning and the windings are fully energized.   A stepper motor also has a detent torque because of its magnet arrangement.  Detent torque is the amount of torque it takes to overcome the magnetic attraction and move a shaft one step from being stopped when the windings are not energized.